# System.Data.SQLite and collate nocase with Vb.net?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net, sqlite

I've a simple select statement that have expected result in DB Browser for SQLite (82 rows).
Same statement return an error in VB.NET using System.Data.SQLite (164 rows)

Statement is: 
SELECT  * FROM  [tblDictionary] INNER JOIN [tblLanguage] ON [tblDictionary].[idLanguage] = [tblLanguage].[idLanguage] WHERE [tblLanguage].[LanguageName] like 'Italian'

In VB.NET is use SQLiteDataReader and rows contain LanguageName Italian and Indonesian

I've tried with following WHERE clause, with the same problem

```
WHERE UPPER([tblLanguage].[LanguageName]) = UPPER('Italian')
WHERE [tblLanguage].[LanguageName] = 'Italian'
```

To replicate problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblLanguage` (
    `idLanguage`    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `LanguageName`  varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `tblDictionary` (
    `idDictionary`  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `idLanguage`    integer NOT NULL,
    `KeyValue`  nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `DataValue` nvarchar(2000) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`idLanguage`) REFERENCES `tblLanguage`(`idLanguage`)
);
INSERT INTO tblLanguage (LanguageName) VALUES ('Indonesian');
INSERT INTO tblLanguage (LanguageName) VALUES ('Italian');
INSERT INTO tblDictionary (idLanguage, KeyValue, DataValue) VALUES (1, 'Delete', 'Hapus');
INSERT INTO tblDictionary (idLanguage, KeyValue, DataValue) VALUES (1, 'Edit', 'Edit');
INSERT INTO tblDictionary (idLanguage, KeyValue, DataValue) VALUES (2, 'Delete', 'Cancella');
INSERT INTO tblDictionary (idLanguage, KeyValue, DataValue) VALUES (2, 'Edit', 'Modifica');
```

VB CODE:

```
Public Function SelectByLanguage(ByVal strLanguage As String) As DataTable
    Dim connection As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=H:\test.db;")
    Dim selectStatement As String _
        = "SELECT " _
        & "     [tblDictionary].[idDictionary] " _
        & "    ,[tblLanguage].[LanguageName] " _
        & "    ,[tblDictionary].[KeyValue] " _
        & "    ,[tblDictionary].[DataValue] " _
        & "FROM " _
        & "     [tblDictionary] " _
        & "INNER JOIN [tblLanguage] ON [tblDictionary].[idLanguage] = [tblLanguage].[idLanguage] " _
        & "WHERE [tblLanguage].[LanguageName] like 'Italian'"
    Dim selectCommand As New SQLiteCommand(selectStatement, connection)
    selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            dt.Load(reader)
        End If
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As SQLiteException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: And what is the problem? That query returns neither 82 nor 164 rows, but 2. And why are you mentioning COLLATE NOCASE, which is not used in your code?

Comment: Exceptions exist to *tell you* what is wrong.  Dont replace them with meaningless messages like "Error"

Comment: I solved it. 
The error message was wrong: ""Impossibile attivare i vincoli. Una o più righe contengono valori che violano il vincolo non-null, unique o foreign-key."
I have inserted in `KeyValue`  nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,
a string with 315 characters ... without error. 
When I done select statement there was that error message.